# How best to handle Rails migrations that add/update/delete data?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I periodically need a script that cleans up or adjusts part of a database in a Rails app. This is often as a result of or in preparation for a migration.

For example, recently I added an explicit `rank` column to a table to enable explicit sorting instead of alphabetical. Once the rank column was added, I needed to populate it for the existing data. This required a script to load the existing data, determine ranks, and save them out to the db. There are lots of examples where scripts like this have been necessary.

The question is, how to handle these scripts so that deployment to production can happen smoothly. I usually write them as migrations, but I often run into issues where the code in the migration works fine when it is written, but when it is run sometime later as part of a deployment, it breaks for various reasons. This latest time it was due to a before_save callback that referenced a column that hadn't yet been added when the migration was run because it was an older migration.

It seems like there could be several strategies:

Strategy 1: Deploy in stages. So if there were two commits A and B that contained migrations that needed to be run before further commits were deployed, you would deploy up to A, then run migrations, then deploy up to B, then run migrations again, and then finally deploy all the way up to HEAD.

Strategy 2: Don't use any AR code in migrations and do everything with SQL. But sometimes AR is just too darn useful.

Strategy 3: Some other trick that I don't know about.

What people do? What is the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally frowned upon to use models in migrations. But it always comes up, I had the very same problem only yesterday.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations

Is quite a helpful guide when it comes to using models in your migration, especially the bit about defining the model in the migration.

Edit: Link not working.
New link:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations

Might not be your version but the same rules apply.

Comment: Links is broken (well, link works, but heading leads to nowhere)